# Poker winning hands

Tags: texas-hold-em

I have a 6,2 and my friend has J,6. The 5 cards in middle are T,T, 6,2,2.

In this case, who wins?

I am thinking me as I have a full house T's and 2 's. But my friend says that top 5 cards needs to be taken into account. So he wins since he has two pairs T's and 6's with J which beats my top 5 cards which are two pairs like above but my 5 th card is 2 compared to my friends J .

I am getting confused with this top 5 cards. Can you also explain me some scenarios where top 5 cards come into picture.

Regards,
 Senthil.

Comment: Looks like your friend is trying to scam you out of some money.

Answer (score 6):

Five best cards win. Your five best cards would be TT222, hence indeed you have a full house which beats his TT66J hand.

Best five cards is always best five cards for the player holding the hand!

Comment: Best hand is TT222 ; )
Need to edit 6 characters for it to save...